# Check if a string has atleast 3 alpha numeric characters in python

Tags: python, regex

How do I find if a string has atleast 3 alpha numeric characters in python. I'm using regex as `"^.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{3, }.*$"`, but it throws error message everytime.

My example string: a&b#cdg1. P

lease let me know.

Comment: Post your code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'a&b#cdg1@'
print len(''.join(i for i in string if i.isalnum()))
```

returns 3

Comment: I think you're backwards. You should be taking the len of `[ch for ch in s if ch.isalnum()]`

Comment: If you could explain step by step what is going on in the 2nd line and how it figures out "if a string has atleast 3 alpha numeric characters in python"

Comment: Thanks for the catch adam, was using the isalnum function backwards. The second line is looping through every item in the string, if it finds a alpha numeric character it joins it to a blank string. The length of the returned string is the amount of alpha numeric characters you have.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
len(re.sub('\W', '', "a&b#cdg1"))
```

as for continuous string with at least 3 alpha numeric characters, you can use this regex pattern

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}'
```